# Django Rest Framework with NextJS

Tags: django-rest-framework, next.js

In short, I would like to use SQL with NextJS but ExpressJS isn't mature as Django for those types of queries.

I would like your opinion on mixing Django Rest Framework with NextJS to offer full support on SSR with the ease to query an SQL database. Would this be a good idea or are there any pitfalls I am not seeing with this logic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NextJS's use of express is really just for serving the frontend. Even if you could do it technically I would advise against using Next's express server as the data fetching backend too.

There is nothing stopping you from using whatever backend tech stack you want in combination with Next, and then calling that backend over REST/GraphQL/MQTT/whatever-you-want from Nexts `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`.

So yes, Django REST will be a perfect match with no specific pitfalls over any other choice of backend.